# How to select a table based on its header from an Excel spreadsheet that contains multiple tables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to interact with a spreadsheet and I have imported it using:

```
InitialImportedData = pd.read_excel(WorkbookLocation, SheetName)
```

The problem is that the spreadsheet I am importing from contains multiple tables, and I only want to use one of them. Is there a way to remove all the rows and columns before a specific value?

The table I am looking for has a header `Premium`. how do I get the table I want as a dataframe rather than all of them with loads of NaN's scattered in my frame?

Is there a way to locate a string in a dataframe and slice it based on that? It is the only one labelled `Premium`.

**edit**

I was able to find the location of the start of my table using:

I solved this in a different way, perhaps useful for people who want to slice up dataframes that they didn't read in through excel.

```
for x in range (InitialImportedData.shape[1]):
    try :
        list(InitialImportedData.iloc[:,x]).index('Premium')
        print list(InitialImportedData.iloc[:,x]).index('Premium'),x        
    except: 
        pass
```

By converting to a list I was able to look where the value sat. I have not worked out how to slice my data correctly at the end.

I can use:

```
InitialImportedData.iloc[20:,4:]
```

to create a dataset which Starts in the corner I need (it happens to be at 20,4) but I have not found a way to slice the end of the table so it doesn't bring in extra information from the worksheet.

I have included an example dataset below:

```
    Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2    Unnamed: 3    Unnamed: 4  \
0          NaN    Table 1           NaN           NaN           NaN   
1          NaN    Header1       Header2           NaN           NaN   
2          NaN    9.88496       2.29552           NaN           NaN   
3          NaN    7.36861        2.6275           NaN           NaN   
4          NaN    5.34938       8.37391           NaN           NaN   
5          NaN    8.77608       3.70626           NaN           NaN   
6          NaN    7.37828       2.62692           NaN           NaN   
7          NaN    6.82297       9.59347           NaN           NaN   
8          NaN     7.6804       7.38528           NaN           NaN   
9          NaN    2.07633       3.76247           NaN           NaN   
10         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
11         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
12         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
13         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
14         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
15         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
16         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
17         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
18         NaN        NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
19         NaN        NaN       Premium           NaN           NaN   
20         NaN        NaN  FinalHeader1  FinalHeader2  FinalHeader3   
21         NaN        NaN      0.679507          8.95       5.87512   
22         NaN        NaN       6.22637       6.54385       4.70131   
23         NaN        NaN       8.84881       6.74557       3.31503   
24         NaN        NaN      0.506901       5.36873       2.42905   
25         NaN        NaN       3.91448      0.542635        8.0885   
26         NaN        NaN        5.4045       9.08379       2.35789   
27         NaN        NaN       4.26343       1.37477      0.719881   
28         NaN        NaN       3.03682       9.62835       1.56601   

    Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  
0          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
1          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
2          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
3          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
4          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
5          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
6          NaN     Table 2         NaN         NaN         NaN  
7          NaN  NewHeader1  NewHeader2  NewHeader3  NewHeader4  
8          NaN      1.2035     2.13923     9.59979     4.90745  
9          NaN    0.273928     9.84469     3.62225     1.07671  
10         NaN     3.67524     9.82434    0.366233      7.9009  
11         NaN     2.16405     2.66321     9.08495     8.29695  
12         NaN     6.77611     7.90381     5.13672     3.26688  
13         NaN     1.95482     1.95997     3.40453    0.702198  
14         NaN     6.39919     5.24728     4.16757     6.06336  
15         NaN     2.34901     9.35103     2.72374     7.39052  
16         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
17         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
18         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
19         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
20         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
21         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
22         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
23         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
24         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
25         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
26         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
27         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
28         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: please clarify what you mean by multiple tables, do you mean 'pages' in excel? Can you please share what this DF looks like ?

Comment: I guess an answer might be along the lines of `index = df.iloc[df['some_column'].str.contains('Premium')]` (untested because we have no example to work with). Please create a repeatable example for us.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I have included an example of the type of data mine looks like.

Comment: @Violatic Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by writing a function as follows:

```
# This function will search for a table within a dataframe, and cut out the section defined with the header specified
# this header must be in the top left, and their must be nothing below or to the right of the table

def CutOutTable(WhereWeAreSearching, WhatWeAreSearchingFor):
    for x in range (WhereWeAreSearching.shape[1]):
        try :
            list(WhereWeAreSearching.iloc[:,x]).index(WhatWeAreSearchingFor)
            WhereToCut = list(WhereWeAreSearching.iloc[:,x]).index(WhatWeAreSearchingFor),x
            SlicedVersionOfWhereWeAreSearching = WhereWeAreSearching.iloc[WhereToCut[0]:,WhereToCut[1]:]
            return SlicedVersionOfWhereWeAreSearching.dropna(axis = 1,how = 'all')
        except:
            pass
```

It looks for the position in the dataframe which contains the phrase you are looking for and cuts information above and to the left of that, followed by removing the columns which contains NaNs to the right of it, thus giving you your whole table. If and only if your table is the bottom rightmost item in your excel worksheet.

Comment: My only comment is formal: Python prefers underscore notation for functions and tends to shorten names: what about e.g `cut_table(start, item)`?

Comment: Hi fralau, I'm still learning what appropriate naming conventions are? Is there a good guide? I just try to be as descriptive as possible so that it's easy to read

Comment: By all means. Your guide is PEP 8 and here is the [relevant excerpt](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) (you may find videos about this on Youtube). But there is another point: perhaps someone taught you to use a **[periphrasis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periphrasis)** (which means "circuitous way of naming things") instead of **naming**? E.g. which one would you naturally use in conversation: "BlackHotBeverageWeBuyEveryMorning" or "coffee"? A sharp, accurate name will cut reading time for your reader, and improve clarity.

Answer (score 0):

That is completely possible. Below is some of my own code that I have done this with. Combo1x is taking the heading "Name" in the sheet "Reference". Hope this helps!

```
filelog=pd.read_excel(desktop,read_only=True, sheetname=None, na_filter=False)


        combo1= Combobox(frame3, state='readonly')
        combo1x=list(filelog['Reference']['Name'])
```

EDIT: One way you could get all the numbers for just "Premium" would to be to take the max row and work backwards with a while statement.

```
ash=logbook["Approvals"]
rows = ash.max_row
mylist=[]

while rows != FinalHeader1
    mylist.append()
    rows -= 1
```

Comment: Could you extend a bit on the meaning of `combo1` and `frame3`?

Comment: @Georgy That was for a GUI I was creating. If you're just parsing data, you can ignore it.

Comment: When I try to run your code with 'Name' as 'Premium' and 'Reference' as InitialDataSheetName, I get KeyError: 'Premium'.

Comment: @Violatic Try doing FinalHeader1 instead of Premium and see if it works.

Comment: @FanMan then I get: KeyError: 'FinalHeader1'

Comment: The last thing I am able to suggest is changing that part to the first value in the table. So the first row in the column you want. That should work. It is difficult to help because I can't see the excel file.